# Python-2.7 multiprocessing module

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, python-multiprocessing

I am using the multiprocessing module in Python in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  The following is the piece of code that I am using:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
out = [pool.apply_async(l1_regularized_func_single_frame,   args=(gradient_x_cube[i,:,:].copy(),gradient_y_cube[i,:,:].copy(),        d_image_dt[i,:,:].copy(),u_prior.copy(),v_prior.copy(), l1_param,mask_indices[j])) for j in range(len(mask_indices))]
output = {key: val for (key,val) in [p.get() for p in out]}
pool.close()            
pool.join()
```

What I am finding is that out of 8 cores, only one core is used to its fullest CPU (~100.0%) and the others are at most (30%) utilization. Could anyone please tell me why am I experiencing such a difference in performance among the cores?

Thanks